# Best practice to run a background Timer within a Service, and fire code after?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Just a few questions to be pointed in the right direction, and show my work so far.

**My Goal:**

- User enters a value (minutes) in an EditText in an Activity window, and presses an OK Button.
- The Activity closes, and then after the set amount of time passes, a new Activity dialog shows.

**My Question(s):**

- Should I be using a Service (or) an IntentService?
- Within the Service running the timer, should I use a Thread to run the code within it?
  Also, if so, should I run the Timer inside one Thread, and then fire the new code in another?
- For the timer code in the Service, should I simply use the AlarmManager *(OR)* a CountdownTimer *(OR)* should I be using some kind of PendingIntent *(OR)* some kind of ASyncTask *(OR)* using the System Clock to determine actual time elapsed? I'm unsure of the best way to go about this, there's so many ways.

**My Work So Far:**

- In Button code, I convert the value entered into the editText to an int representing the time entered in minutes, then back to a String so it can be passed to the Service using putExtra with the Intent.

  // IDENTIFY THE EditText
      EditText editText_timerValue;
      editText_timerValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_timerValue);

  ```
  // MAKE SURE A VALUE HAS BEEN ENTERED, AND AVOID NullPointerException
  if (editText_timerValue != null) {

      // CONVERT USER-DATA FROM THE EditText TO AN INT
      int int_timerValue_Ms;
      int_timerValue_Ms = Integer.parseInt(editText_timerValue.getText().toString());
      // CONVERT USER-DATA FROM (Integer = MilliSeconds) TO (Minutes)
      int int_timerValue_Min;
      int_timerValue_Min = int_timerValue_Ms * 60000;

      // CONVERT INT BACK TO A STRING SO IT CAN BE PASSED USING putExtra
      String string_timerValue_Min;
      string_timerValue_Min = String.valueOf(int_timerValue_Min);

      // DECLARE INTENT FOR STARTING THE TIMER SERVICE
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);

      // PASS THE VALUE OF THE EditText WITH THE INTENT THAT STARTS SERVICE
      intent.putExtra("TIMER_VALUE", string_timerValue_Min);

      // START TIMER SERVICE (RUNS BACKGROUND TIMER, PERFORMS ACTIONS WHEN EXPIRED)
      startService(intent);

      // CLOSE THE CURRENT ACTIVITY, AS THE TIMER SERVICE RUNS IN THE BACKGROUND
      finish();

      // IF NO VALUE HAS BEEN ENTERED INTO THE EditText
      } else {

      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter a Value in Minutes!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  ```

I'm not too worried about my work shown - I'm more concerned with how I should go about setting the timer, as from what I gather there are multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: This question is too broad. There is no "best way" to do this. There are, as you have already determined, many ways to do this. A lot of them aren't significant;y different in terms of pros and cons. I don't think this question is appropriate for Stackoverflow as you can always find an argument to support one way or another way. My suggestion: find something that works for you and move on to other things. If you have a specific, concrete problem, open another question.

Comment: @DavidWasser Perhaps a dialog about the best practice could be useful? But in my case, I found an old project I had previously been working on that uses a CountdownTimer to achieve the goal, so I suppose i'll run with that. Thanks.